# Match two files and print the matched strings based on the second file using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have two files below named InputFile and Ref

InputFile

```
1234~code1=yyy:code2=fff:code3=vvv
1256~code2=ttt:code1=yyy:code4=zzz
4567~code4=uuu
8907~code8=ooo:code7=rrr
```

Ref

```
code2
code3
code8
code7
```

I have to match all the records in Ref to InputFile's second column (~ delimited and will be split by colon(:)). If a record in Ref is found in InputFile, it should print the preceding value after the = sign otherwise print none.

Desired output

```
1234~fff~vvv~~
1256~ttt~~~
4567~~~~
8907~~~ooo~rrr
```

I'm about to load it to a table having the Ref records as the columns.

Here's my script as of:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="~"
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]
  next
}
FNR==1 && FNR!=NR{
  print
  next
}
{
  num=split($2,array,"[=:]")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i+=2){
    if(array[i] in a){
      val=val?val OFS array[i+1]:array[i+1]
    }
    else{
      val=val?val OFS "~":"~"
    }
  }
  print $1,val
  val=""
}
' Ref InputFile
```

It prints the array (code1,code2,etc) in InputFile that is present in Ref but it doesn't print in Ref's order.

Script's output

```
1234~~fff~vvv
1256~ttt
4567~
8907~ooo~rrr
```

Comment: Is `output` your actual output or another version of your desired output? The order of lines in both your desired output earlier in the post and that last "output" looks identical to me, it's just some fields that are missing - is that an issue or is the order the only issue? What does `in Ref's order` mean? The order of lines in the Ref file or alphabetic or numeric order of the contents of the Ref file or something else?

Comment: The last output is the script's actual output which is not acceptable since I will be uploading the output in a table wherein the columns are already defined. The columns in the table are listed in the Ref file so the output must be aligned in the ref file. Eg, if code2 (in ref file) is found in the input file, print the value, else blank; next; if code3 is found in the input file, print the value, else blak;next...and so on.

Answer (score 0):

something similar to yours

```
$ awk -F~ 'NR==FNR {c[NR]=$1; cs=NR; next} 
                   {n=split($2,f,"[=:]"); 
                    delete k; 
                    for(i=1;i<n;i+=2) k[f[i]]=f[i+1]; 
                    printf "%s", $1; 
                    for(i=1;i<=cs;i++) printf "%s", FS k[c[i]]; 
                    print ""}' ref input
1234~fff~vvv~~
1256~ttt~~~
4567~~~~
8907~~~ooo~rrr
```

since you want to keep the order in the ref file, don't insert them as keys to the array, instead add them as values indexed with the order number (here the line number).  Otherwise you're going to lose order, which I think it the (only?) issue with your script.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS  = "[~:=]"
    OFS = "~"
}
NR == FNR {
    refs[++numRefs] = $0
    next
}
{
    delete ref2val
    for (fldNr=2; fldNr<NF; fldNr+=2) {
        ref2val[$fldNr] = $(fldNr+1)
    }

    printf "%s%s", $1, OFS
    for (refNr=1; refNr<=numRefs; refNr++) {
        ref = refs[refNr]
        printf "%s%s", ref2val[ref], (refNr<numRefs ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk refs file
1234~fff~vvv~~
1256~ttt~~~
4567~~~~
8907~~~ooo~rrr
```